# How to use a AI model's checkpoints for detecting

Tags: model, artificial-intelligence

I'm writing a google colab note for my presentation. It's about training a model to recognize emotion in input text. I finished train this model with my own data, got checkpoint file (saved in /content/minilm-finetuned-emotion) but I have no idea how to use these checkpoint to detect emotion appearing in text :((
Here is link to my google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RFyazKIgn07uxZJGsZI7miO33TjL0E5i?usp=sharing
Thank you so much for helping!

I try use pipeline function from hugging face but it seem calling API to huggingface'hub. However my purpose is running the model directly on google colab... Still then I got no idea how to do that